# Please help me with the identification of this rock

Tags: minerals

What is it? It has what looks like white glitter its ugly dark brown and some orange heavy..[image]

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but you need to [read this guide](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions/125#125) and provide a lot more information. And a better picture.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you reacted that way. Look, nobody could identify your rock based on the first photo, but you posted a better photo. That's a great improvement. So now, all you need to do is add in some information such as where you found it, and some other things in the guide I linked ro.

Comment: Whatever it is it appears to be very heavily iron stained, that could make a solid identification rather difficult.

Comment: I don't want to be insistent, but I think the list is too much long. There are who understand it and read it, but some off them just get away. It is not the only site to ask on the net. Maybe to put a header with basic things and then the list as a kind of "read more".

Comment: @A.Carrillo: Spencer just told you the standart of the site when someone post an inaccurate picture or do not provide basic information for geologists to identify it. We all do as we have an agreement to share the guide to have better posts for students. Sometimes the identification only needs the picture, but here we need more info about the outcrop.

Comment: @A.Carrillo: Psychologists say there are 30 types of inteligence. I apologize for our mistakes with this tag, but please be polite.